# Why does php download stop on large files?

Tags: php

I have a php script that allows users to download large files. The script works well except for files of over around 500mb. Everytime I try to download a file that is 664mb the download stops at about 460mb ( around 15-17 mins). There is no error. What can I do? I 
suspect the script is timing out but I can't see why. I've spent days trying to get it to work and just can't make any progress. Any thoughts or suggestions would be great. I'm using a hosted server so cannot try `modx_sendfile`  sadly. I'm using php 7.0.25

```
$db = new mysqli($dbHost, $dbUsername, $dbPassword, $dbName);

ob_start() or die('Cannot start output buffering');
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
ini_set('display_startup_errors', 1);
error_reporting(E_ALL);

$strDownloadFolder = "files/";
//- turn off compression on the server
//@apache_setenv('no-gzip', 1);
@ini_set('zlib.output_compression', 'Off');

//Download a file more than once
$boolAllowMultipleDownload = 2;
if(!empty($_GET['key'])){
    //check the DB for the key
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM downloads WHERE downloadkey = '".mysqli_real_escape_string($db,$_GET['key'])."' LIMIT 1";
    $resCheck=mysqli_query($db, $sql);
      $arrCheck = mysqli_fetch_array($resCheck); //Create array from first result
    if(!empty($arrCheck['file'])){
        //check that the download time hasnt expired
        if($arrCheck['expires']>=time()){
            if(!$arrCheck['downloads'] OR $boolAllowMultipleDownload){

                //everything is ok -let the user download it
                $strDownload = $strDownloadFolder.$arrCheck['file'];
                if(file_exists($strDownload)){


$file_path  = $arrCheck['file'];
$path_parts = pathinfo($file_path);
$file_name  = $path_parts['basename'];
$file_ext   = $path_parts['extension'];
$file_path  = 'files/' . $file_name;


// allow a file to be streamed instead of sent as an attachment
$is_attachment = isset($_REQUEST['stream']) ? false : true;

// make sure the file exists
if (is_file($file_path))
{
    $file_size  = filesize($file_path);
    $file = @fopen($file_path,"rb");
    if ($file)
    {
        // set the headers, prevent caching
        header("Pragma: public");
        header("Expires: -1");
        header("Cache-Control: public, must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0");
        header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=\"$file_name\"");

        // set appropriate headers for attachment or streamed file
        if ($is_attachment) {
                header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=\"$file_name\"");
        }
        else {
                header('Content-Disposition: inline;');
                header('Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary');
        }

        // set the mime type based on extension, add yours if needed.
        $ctype_default = "application/octet-stream";
        $content_types = array(
                "exe" => "application/octet-stream",
                "zip" => "application/zip",
                "mp3" => "audio/mpeg",
                "mpg" => "video/mpeg",
                "avi" => "video/x-msvideo",
        );
        $ctype = isset($content_types[$file_ext]) ? $content_types[$file_ext] : $ctype_default;
        header("Content-Type: " . $ctype);

        //check if http_range is sent by browser (or download manager)
        if(isset($_SERVER['HTTP_RANGE']))
        {
            list($size_unit, $range_orig) = explode('=', $_SERVER['HTTP_RANGE'], 2);
            if ($size_unit == 'bytes')
            {

                list($range, $extra_ranges) = explode(',', $range_orig, 2);
            }
            else
            {
                $range = '';
                header('HTTP/1.1 416 Requested Range Not Satisfiable');
                exit;
            }
        }
        else
        {
            $range = '';
        }

        //figure out download piece from range (if set)
        list($seek_start, $seek_end) = explode('-', $range, 2);

        //set start and end based on range (if set), else set defaults
        //also check for invalid ranges.
        $seek_end   = (empty($seek_end)) ? ($file_size - 1) : min(abs(intval($seek_end)),($file_size - 1));
        $seek_start = (empty($seek_start) || $seek_end < abs(intval($seek_start))) ? 0 : max(abs(intval($seek_start)),0);

        //Only send partial content header if downloading a piece of the file (IE workaround)
        if ($seek_start > 0 || $seek_end < ($file_size - 1))
        {
            header('HTTP/1.1 206 Partial Content');
            header('Content-Range: bytes '.$seek_start.'-'.$seek_end.'/'.$file_size);
            header('Content-Length: '.($seek_end - $seek_start + 1));
        }
        else
          header("Content-Length: $file_size");

        header('Accept-Ranges: bytes');

        set_time_limit(0);
        fseek($file, $seek_start);

        while(!feof($file)) 
        {
            print(@fread($file, 1024*8));
            ob_flush();
            flush();
            if (connection_status()!=0) 
            {
                @fclose($file);
                exit;
            }           
        }

        // file save was a success
        @fclose($file);
        exit;
    }
    else 
    {
        // file couldn't be opened
        header("HTTP/1.0 500 Internal Server Error");
        exit;
    }
}
else
{
    // file does not exist
    header("HTTP/1.0 404 Not Found");
    exit;
}





                    }else{
                    echo "We couldn't find the file to download.";

                }
            }else{
                //this file has already been downloaded and multiple downloads are not allowed
                echo "This file has already been downloaded.";
            }
        }else{
            //this download has passed its expiry date
            echo "This download has expired.";
        }
    }else{
        //the download key given didnt match anything in the DB
        echo "No file was found to download.";
    }
}else{
    //No download key wa provided to this script
    echo "No download key was provided. Please return to the previous page and try again.";
}
```

A much simpler piece of code that still throws up the same problem (but works with smaller files) mkaes me think it is a hosting / php.ini issue although I don't know why.

```
<?php
$local_file = 'my_big_file.zip';
$download_file = 'my_big_file.zip';

// set the download rate limit (=> 20,5 kb/s)

if(file_exists($local_file) && is_file($local_file))
{
    header('Cache-control: private');
    header('Content-Type: application/octet-stream');
    header('Content-Length: '.filesize($local_file));
    header('Content-Disposition: filename='.$download_file);

    flush();
    $file = fopen($local_file, "r");
    while(!feof($file))
    {
        // send the current file part to the browser
        print fread($file, round(1024 * 1024));
        // flush the content to the browser
        flush();
        // sleep one second
        sleep(1);
    }
    fclose($file);}
else {
    die('Error: The file '.$local_file.' does not exist!');
}

?>
```

This script stops downloading after about 17  minutes.

Comment: Is it shared hosting? It could be that the hosting provider is killing long running processes to keep the server available for other tenants.

Comment: I noticed you read until `EOF` and not until `$seek_end`.

Comment: I spoke to hoster and they instructed me to 'execution time to 300 or 400' and increase 'Upload vars to 3000' in the php.ini file. Not sure what they meant about 'Upload vars' but I increased the max_execution_time but still the same problem persists.

Comment: make your script run infinite with `ini_set('time_limit', 0)` to make sure the download completes

Comment: Thanks.  I tried ini_set('time_limit', 0) but still get the same results.

Comment: As Bojan Bedrac suggested earlier I contacted my service provider and they 'hinted' I needed to be on a 'pro' package with dedicated IP and not sharing bandwidth with other users. I signed up and things seem to be much more reliable (thought not 100 %).